# How to replace the text between () and the () themselves in Looker Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a field that has Name and EEID, i.e. John W (121231) and I need to keep only the name. Any suggested formula please?

I tried below formula but it didn't work, any suggestion?

REGEXP_REPLACE(Management Chain - Level 01,"(*)","")

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
REGEXP_REPLACE(Name + EEID,"\\(.*\\)","")
```

[image]